# Where is the setting saved when I modify a configuration setting?

Tags: 8, configuration

When I modify a setting from a custom module, where is that saved?  How can I get that setting without exporting the configuration?

Comment: They are saved in the `config` table, BLOB data value, in the Database. You can save and access them as Jeff's answer link shows.

Comment: If you still don't get the docs, take a look at a module that saves & retrives config settings, and see how it does it.

Comment: I am closing this question as too broad, since the question doesn't even show the code used to save the settings, nor make clear what _setting_ mean in the specific case. In Drupal there are more ways to store a value a module can to retrieve later, including storing the value in a custom database table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/configuration/simple

See the section on *Interacting with configuration* and *Reading configuration*.

E.g. `$config = \Drupal::config('system.performance');`

I'm assuming the saved settings are configuration.